# Limits of quad integration in scipy with np.inf

Tags: python, scipy

Here an example with results:

I integrate through Gaussian distribution(mu=800, sigma=1) with ~ +-2sigma ppf and same integral from `-inf` to `+inf`. For some reason second integral results in zero, but in practice it should be more accurate.

Can someone explain, why such anomaly happens or where i made a mistake?

code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

def integrand(x):
    return x*norm.pdf(x, 800, 1)
print quad(integrand, norm.ppf(0.05, 800,1), norm.ppf(0.95, 800,1))
print quad(integrand, -np.inf, np.inf)

(719.9999999999894, 5.913323331834147e-11)
(0.0, 0.0)
```

EDIT: By the way, when mean is small( for example 2) , it works fine - both integrals results are very close.

Comment: I don't see the problem here. You do realize the second integral is _supposed_ to be zero, right? (You're integrating an odd function, x times the PDF, over a symmetric interval)

Comment: No, it should be the expected value of the distribution, which, in his case, is 800. It seems to be an issue with the integration method. If you replace your expected value with 1, you get the correct result

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be mean?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about the shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quad` use heuristic algorithms, using adaptative step of integration to reduce time computing. Where the function is flat, it goes faster. so on big global interval, it can miss the peak.

You can help `quad` by suggesting  "points of interest", to help him to find the regions with difficulties :

```
>>> quad(integrand,0,1000)
(3.8929062783235445e-32, 7.210678067622767e-32)
>>> quad(integrand,0,1000,points=[750])
(799.9999999999993, 2.0260999142842332e-07)
```

You can see the result of `quad` investigations with the `full_output` keyword :

```
>>>quad(integrand,0,1000,full_output=True)[2]['rlist'].max()
3.8929062783235445e-32
```

Here `quad` never select points where the integrand value exceed 1e-31, so it
infer that the function is null everywhere.

Comment: Note that `points` can not be used when the domain is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this behavior is expected.

When limits of integration is so huge - from -inf to inf, it is hard for `quad` to find relatively small bump at around 800, so the result of integral will be zero.

The reason it works when mean is small, is because the first split `quad` doing at the middle of given range which is zero, so when mean is small, integral will find the positive values at first split. (Probably it using some sort of trapezoid integration, i am not sure). So solution to this problem will be : Or give limits of integral a real numbers(making our search space much much smaller) Or making sure one of the splits will find positive values in range.(For example making sure that the mean is around zero).